# Failed to load libGL.so on Android

Tags: android

I am using [Ubuntu 12.04](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_12.04_LTS_.28Precise_Pangolin.29) (Precise Pangolin) with the Oracle [JDK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Development_Kit) 7, and when I am running the Android emulator from [Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29), it's giving this error:

```
[2012-07-04 02:52:10 - Emulator] error libGL.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory 
[2012-07-04 02:52:10 - Emulator] Failed to load libGL.so
```

Also the emulator is very slow. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

I have the Android SDK installed into ~/android-sdk-linux_x86, so I did:

```
ln -s /usr/lib/libGL.so.1 ~/android-sdk-linux_x86/tools/lib/libGL.so
```

This solves errors just like linking to /usr/lib does, but it doesn't require root and doesn't mess with core system directories.

Comment: This combined with libo's "apt-get" command is the cleanest solution here.

Comment: If you don't already have libGL.so.1, you may need to use the solution by libo, but this is the cleanest place to link the file.

No need to put 32 bit in 64 bit libs....

Comment: `locate libGL` at first may help

Comment: I used `find / -name 'libGL.so.1'` and located it in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` on `debian jessie`.

Answer (score 35):

On 64-bit Ubuntu 12.04, do it like this:

```
$ sudo apt-get install git-core gnupg flex bison gperf build-essential \
  zip curl libc6-dev libncurses5-dev:i386 x11proto-core-dev \
  libx11-dev:i386 libreadline6-dev:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 \
  libgl1-mesa-dev g++-multilib mingw32 openjdk-6-jdk tofrodos \
  python-markdown libxml2-utils xsltproc zlib1g-dev:i386
$ sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so
```

Source: *[Installing required packages (Ubuntu 12.04)](http://source.android.com/source/initializing.html)*

Comment: this screwed up my system

Comment: This answer in combination with answer - http://askubuntu.com/a/144194 for solving dependencies (use aptitude to locate the dependency and see what is causing the problem) , and eventually running a command `sudo apt-get install --reinstall gcc-4.7-multilib` as I found on answer http://askubuntu.com/a/236114

Comment: I had to do "sudo apt-get install libglapi-mesa" and then "sudo apt-get install libx11-dev:i386 libreadline6-dev:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386" first

Comment: I think I didn't had to install libGL for x86, it was enough to use ./sdk/tools/emulator64-x86? (note the '64')

Comment: Oh man, posting huge lines of app-installment without any kind of explanation or warning ain't good.

Answer (score 32):

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit. Using the following command to solve the problem

```
 sudo ln -s /usr/lib32/fglrx/libGL.so.1.2 /usr/lib/libGL.so
```

**Note**: This is applicable only to those who use the AMD/ATI graphic drivers.

Comment: This worked for me too, I think this only works for ATI cards. This is technically wrong as it symlinks 32 bit shared library into the (64 bit) /lib/ directory, but it looks like the Android emulator will only look there for this lib.

Comment: I would recommend doing a file search for libGL.so and adjusting the link command based on the location. Mine happened to be at: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa

Comment: Mine was at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so but it caused an error if I tried to run cause it wanted a 32-bit lib and I supplied a 64-bit lib

Answer (score 32):

For 32-bit Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, this worked:

```
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev
```

None of the following worked:

```
cd /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/
sudo ln -s libGL.so.1.2 libGL.so 
sudo ln -s libGL.so.1.2 /usr/lib/libGL.so
ln -s libGL.so.1.2 ~/android/android-sdk-linux/tools/lib/libGL.so
```

Comment: Works with 13.04. Note that if you put a symlink in the tools/lib directory you have to remove it again.

Comment: The apt-get command also worked on Ubuntu 13.04 x64, no need for symlink.

Answer (score 14):

What works for me (ubuntu 12.04 64bit) was just to run :

```
    sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev
```

I found that `libGL.so` exists in directory `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`

Installation of 32 bit version was not working.

Answer (score 6):

On 64 bit Ubuntu 12.04, there is no /usr/lib64. It is /usr/lib only.
Also, on my machine, libGL.so isn't present. Instead the file is libGLEW.so

To install /usr/lib/LibGL.so you can run:
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev

However, it didn't solve the problem for me. In fact, it probably screwed up my system.

Comment: Checked with Synaptic,  libgl1-mesa-dev installs libGL.so to /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so

Comment: GLEW is a different library, the [OpenGL Extension Wrangler](http://glew.sourceforge.net/).  It's not an "instead", it's something that programs can use in *addition* to libGL.

Answer (score 4):

I think I got it right, no warnings and no slowness... This might not work with proprietary drivers, though.

Make sure libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 is installed (even if you got a x64 SO file). Then do:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.2 /usr/lib/libGL.so
```

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me on 64 bit Ubuntu 12.10 and the ADT bundle:

```
ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1 ~/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64/sdk/tools/lib/libGL.so
```

If you don't have `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1` just install `libgl1-mesa-glx`

```
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-glx
```

Answer (score 3):

Referring to http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html, I installed ia32-libs and did:

```
ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.2 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so
```

That's all I did to solve this problem.

Comment: Nice, but I had to use `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa` instead

Answer (score 3):

NVidia Optimus:

Running on dual graphics (intel and nvidia), I used the following:

1. Install Bumblebee (see: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee#Installation)
2. Install the required lib.
3. Run the emulator on the nvidia discrete card.

This should do the trick:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia linux-headers-generic 
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

Whenever you wish to run the emulator, just use optirun:

```
optirun emulator @<avd_name>
```

I should give a warning that I only installed Linux yesterday. So I don't really know what I'm doing….

Answer (score 3):

I use [Linux Mint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Mint) 14 - 64 bit and for me, it worked :) :

```
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dev
```

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit, [GNOME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME) 3.4, I first referred to http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html and installed ia32-lib, which will generate /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.2.0

Then I run the below command and solved this problem:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.2.0 /usr/lib/libGL.so
```

This is slightly different from gridstation's answer.

I guess there's no need to install the Mesa driver locally, which may cause issues with your real video drivers.

Answer (score 2):

To make it work on a [Ubuntu 12.10](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_13.04_.28Raring_Ringtail.29) (Quantal Quetzal) 64-bit, you have to do two things:

1) You have to initialize LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Example:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/tests/android/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64/sdk/tools/lib
```

Comments: change the path to your location

2) You have to create a symbolic link

a) Use `locate libGL` to find the correct library:

```
rudy@vsolutions:~$ locate libGL
/home/rudy/opt/android/android-sdk-linux/tools/lib/libGLES_CM_translator.so
/home/rudy/opt/android/android-sdk-linux/tools/lib/libGLES_V2_translator.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGLU.so.1
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGLU.so.1.3.1
...
/usr/lib32/nvidia-current/libGL.so.304.43
```

b) Create the soft link

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.2.0 /usr/lib/libGL.so
```

Comments: use a 64-bit library on a 64-bit operating system!

**Now start the emulator**
My system is [Optimus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nvidia_Optimus), and I have installed [Bumblebee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nvidia_Optimus#Bumblebee). I can use "Intel Open Source Technology Center" "Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ironlake Mobile " "2.1 Mesa 9.0" or "NVIDIA Corporation" "GeForce GT 330M/PCIe/SSE2" "3.3.0 NVIDIA 304.43".

a) Intel

```
/home/rudy/tests/android/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64/sdk//tools/emulator64-arm -avd avd_42 -scale 0.46 -gpu on -verbose
```

b) Nvidia

```
optirun /home/rudy/tests/android/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64/sdk//tools/emulator64-arm -avd avd_42 -scale 0.46 -gpu on -verbose
```

Comments:

- I didn't see any difference between the Intel and the Nvidia cards... It is certainly because the emulator is not [GPU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_processing_unit) intensive.
- On my system an Intel Core i5, it took almost 1 minute to start the emulator... Please be patient... I find the emulator rather fast after it is loaded (the 1 minute to wait). If you start the emulator from the [Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29) [IDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment), then the emulator does a software emulation (the GPU is off) and took 1 min 30 to start... It is much more slower than using the Intel or Nvidia cards!!!
- `verbose` is the parameter to use to display more diagnostics
- `optirun` is the command to make use of the Nvidia on Bumblebee. If you don't have Bumblebee don't use it!
- `avd` is a virtual device
- `gpu on` to make use of the graphical card

Answer (score 2):

**On Ubuntu 64 bit,**

**1. Check libGL,**

```
$ locate libGL.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.2.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.2.0
```

**2. Create a symlink where the SDK is installed**

```
ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1 /usr/local/android-studio/sdk/tools/lib/libGL.so
```

Comment: I can confirm that this resolves the issue under Ubuntu 64bit.

Answer (score 1):

**OSError: libGL.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory**

It may appear on Linux systems when you try to launch VNL for the first time. 
To solve it, create (as administrator) a new link in `/usr/lib` :

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libGL.so.1.2 /usr/lib/libGL.so
```

If you have a 64-bit Linux, use `/usr/lib64 instead` .

First check that you actually have `libGL.so.1.2` in `/usr/lib` or `/usr/lib64` ; it might be called `libGL.so.1` or something else instead, or located in another directory, depending on the video drivers.

You can use locate `libGL` to find the correct file to link to.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to user1289608, I was able to do a sym link from an existing install of Mesa:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.2 /usr/lib/libGL.so
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.  But in my case, I solved it another (I think, better) way.

In my situation (Lubuntu 13.10), it was enough to simply also install the library `libgl1-mesa-dev` through Synaptic Package manager (the `libgl1-mesa-dri` library was already installed by default when the Lubuntuu distro was set up).

That solves all the hassle of putting links from one file to the other and also prevents polluting your system:

- How will you know after several months (or years) what dedicated links you've put to keep the system running?
- What about a future updates, if you start to do those things yourself?  Will something be broken/not updated due to "manual intervention"?

If you use the "system mechanism", it's all done for you.  And correctly done.  That's why those tools are there in the first place.

Best rgds,

Comment: Just now saw that @Tanyasipeti did the same through apt-get.  But in my case, it solved the issue completely.  I got the emulator up and running.

Comment: I just figured it out myself for 13.10 and wanted to add something similar as an answer!

Answer (score 0):

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit. Linking `/usr/lib64/libGLC.so.0` to `/usr/lib64/libGL.so` seems to solve the problem.

**EDIT:** It stops the error messages, but the emulator is still slow for me.

Comment: Yes, the emulator is incredibly slow for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

Restart the adb from the DDMS:
In Eclipse: Window > Open Perspective... > Other > DDMS.  Select the emulator from the left side pane and select "Restart adb"

You can also restart the adb server from the terminal window.

```
android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb kill-server
android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb start-server
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Reinstalling the [Nvidia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nvidia) driver fixed the [segmentation fault](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault) for me.

Answer (score 0):

I found the folder for libGL by the command "locate"

It turned out to be in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/

> ~$ locate libGL 
>   /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGLEW.so.1.8
>   /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGLEW.so.1.8.0
>   /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGLEWmx.so.1.8
>   /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGLEWmx.so.1.8.0
>   /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGLU.so.1
>   /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGLU.so.1.3.1
>   /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1
>   /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.2.0

Answer (score 0):

For my Debian 7 'Wheezy' installation I used the following command:

```
ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 opt/android/tools/lib/libGL.so
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev
cd ~/Development/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140321/sdk/tools/lib
unlink libGL.so 
ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.2.0 libGL.so
```

that's it!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem because I had checked "Use Host GPU" when creating my AVD. I tried it with that option unchecked and I was able to successfully start the emulator. This is acceptable for my testing purposes, but if using the host GPU is important you'll probably want to try some of the other solutions here.

Answer (score -1):

I solved this problem by reinstalling libgl1, both the 64- and 32-bit libraries:

```
$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
```

Background: Previously I switched from the free radeon driver back to fglrx. I guess this somehow screwed up my libgl1, because fglrx comes with its own version.

Besides, I think that the other solutions provided here are possibly dangerous, because it is wrong to symlink 32 bit shared libraries into the (64 bit) /lib/ directory.

Answer (score -2):

Check if you have `libgl1-mesa-*` packages installed. If so, install the `libgl1-mesa-dev` package to get the unversioned shared objects.

You shouldn't have to do this -- it's the Android team's error. Give them a break, they're only Java developers.

Comment: i already have mesa-libGL-dev in my system, but still have the error

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu 11.10 32-bit. I installed libgl1-mesa-dev and there was no longer an error message when starting the emultor. I did not need to perform any linking, but maybe this would be required on 64-bit?