# Android Emulator for Ubuntu 12.10 (Arm installation)?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ubuntu, arm

Since it is possible to run Ubuntu 12.10 with Eclipse on an arm device (when compiling the right arm kernel into ubuntu) Compiling android projects is also easily possible.

Now does anyone know how to accomplish to run an android emulator out of Eclipse under Ubuntu 12.10 (ARM installation of Ubuntu)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11332817/failed-to-load-libgl-so-in-android

Answer (score 0):

If you are running a 64-bit distribution on your development machine, you need to install the ia32-libs package using apt-get::

Open a terminal and run the below command

```
apt-get install ia32-libs
```

http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html