# Error libGL.so: cannot open shared object file using Android emulator

Tags: android, ubuntu-12.04

I was trying to run android emulator in Ubuntu 12.04(64-bit). But, I got the following errors.

```
Starting emulator for AVD 'emulatr'
Failed to load libGL.so
error libGL.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Failed to load libGL.so
error libGL.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered
```

After using  `locate libGL.` I found

```
/home/adnan/android-sdk-linux/tools/lib/libGL.so
/usr/lib/libGL.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.2.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.2.0
```

I also tried some solution from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11332817/failed-to-load-libgl-so-in-android) But, didn't work. I will be glad, if you guys help to solve this problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As I'm using 64-bit Ubuntu 12.04. So, I did this

```
$ sudo apt-get install git-core gnupg flex bison gperf build-essential \
  zip curl libc6-dev libncurses5-dev:i386 x11proto-core-dev \
  libx11-dev:i386 libreadline6-dev:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 \
  libgl1-mesa-dev g++-multilib mingw32 openjdk-6-jdk tofrodos \
  python-markdown libxml2-utils xsltproc zlib1g-dev:i386
$ sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so
```

Answer (score 58):

http://learnedstuffs.wordpress.com/2012/07/17/fixing-ubuntu-error-failed-to-load-libgl-so/

```
apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev
```

worked for me

Comment: It also works for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I appreciate the information, It has been useful.

Comment: How to fix same issue in RHEL?

Comment: how to use this in Kaggle?

Answer (score 9):

On Fedora

```
sudo yum install mesa-libGL-devel
```

Answer (score 3):

This works for me on **Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit**:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dri
$ sudo ln -sv /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the development files for libgl1-mesa, so instead you should/could install `libgl1-mesa-dri` instead of `libgl1-mesa-dev` as suggested by others.
This saves you a couple of MB of unnecessary files.

Furthermore, the Android applications are either 32 bit or 64 bit.

For a or a 32 bit Ubuntu you require the 32 bit SDK (as 64 bit does not work):

```
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dri
```

Same goes for a 64-bit Ubuntu with a 64-bit SDK.

But for a 64 bit Ubuntu in combination with a 32 bit SDK, you need to specify that you require the 32 bit version of the package:

```
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dri:i386
```

Answer (score 0):

I too had this problem (fedora 20), but the libGL files already existed on my filesystem.  Based on an examination of the libraries on an older fedora 18 installation, I found that I could resolve the problem by providing a symbolic link for libGL.so linking to libGL.so.1.2.0.