# Qt: can't find -lGL error

Tags: c++, qt, compiler-construction, qt-creator, ubuntu-13.04

I just reinstalled QtCreator, created new project (*Qt Application*) an got this after compilation:

```
/usr/bin/ld: **cannot find -lGL**
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [untitled1] Error 1
18:07:41: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project untitled1 (kit: Desktop Qt 5.1.0 GCC 32bit)
When executing step 'Make'
```

(*Project is empty, I did'n commit any changes*)

> Qt Creator 2.7.2
>   Based on Qt 5.1.0 (32 bit)
>   Ubuntu 13.04

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: do you have opengl installed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android : error libGL.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17417211/android-error-libgl-so-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-direct)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Qt Creator compiler issue on Debian](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33254272/qt-creator-compiler-issue-on-debian)

Answer (score 186, accepted):

You should install package "libgl1-mesa-dev":

```
sudo apt install libgl1-mesa-dev
```

Comment: How is this the correct answer? Why should you link against a library not being used? Shouldn't the linker flags simply not include `-lGL`?

Comment: @Cuadue: The GL in the error and in libgl1-... is for OpenGL, a fundamental dependency of Qt 5.x. This is a common error for devs when setting up for Qt development -- but once they install the OpenGL development lib they never see it again.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 ships with the required OpenGL libraries, it's not necessary to install any packages, you just need to use `ln` to create a link in /usr/lib, see [destan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32184137/4975230), the [20.04 package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/amd64/libgl1-mesa-dev/filelist) doesn't seem to have anything useful in it.

Answer (score 81):

you don't need to install anything. `libGL` is already installed with Ubuntu, you just need to soft link it. (tested for ubuntu 14.x and 15.x, might work for later versions)

1. First locate the GL library
2. Then link it under /usr/lib
3. If the library is missing, it can be installed via libgl1-mesa-dev package

Here is how you could do this:

```
$ locate libGL
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.2.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLEW.so.1.10
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLEW.so.1.10.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLEWmx.so.1.10
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLEWmx.so.1.10.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so.1.3.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.2.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa-egl/libGLESv2.so.2
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa-egl/libGLESv2.so.2.0.0
$ sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1 /usr/lib/libGL.so
```

Comment: Yep, this works. It's usually a good idea to run `ldconfig` after dealing with shared libraries like in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! On my system I had multiple libGL because of Android sdk, steam and other applications. The original mesa folder was also present in `i386-linux-gnu` folder. For anyone reading this answer, you can easily locate the default installed library in Ubuntu by running `locate libGL | grep mesa` and then alter the last `sudo ln` command mentioned in this answer with the right location.

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu 16.10, but I'm confused if it is now using the NVidia GPU for OpenGL rendering, or a s/w renderer?

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to solve the pkg-config question, does it? IE: if you have qt build lines set up to use pkg-config --libs, this solution still won't return anything for GL? 

To be on the safe side, I simply installed the mesa-dev.

Comment: You Sir, deserve the cookie not the con-man who was the big tick

Comment: For me on Ubuntu 18.04 I link it on the same location using following command. sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.0.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so

Comment: linking the file did not solve the problem in my case, the compiler complained:
`/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/7/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libGL.so when searching for -lGL
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/7/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL`

Comment: That worked for my on Ubuntu 18.04 and Qt 5.12.6. `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 /usr/lib/libGL.so`

Comment: I'd like to recommend this solution. It worked with my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and Qt 5.0.2 (5.15.2 based) `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1 /usr/lib/libGL.so
`

Answer (score 4):

The gui Qt module is [included by default](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#qt). If you don't want to use it in a project (e.g., it is a library or only uses stdio), you need to specify that in the .pro file.

```
QT -= gui
```

And the linker won't attempt to find lGL regardless of whether it is installed.

My case is admittedly a bit odd, since the main reason to use Qt is to create gui's. Installing the GL library is certainly not difficult, I just wanted to know why my quick and dirty Hello World wanted it.

Answer (score 2):

write:

```
yum provides */libGL.so
```

after providing:

```
yum install mesa-libGL-devel mesa-libGLU-devel
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libEGL1.so /usr/lib/libGL.so
```

Answer (score 1):

My system is Ubuntu 16.04 on x86 computer(with NVIDIA GeForce GPU).

Check the library files located in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`

```
ls -al /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libG*
```

If you see the broken link, reinstall `libgl1-mesa-glx`

```
sudo apt install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-glx
```

And, recheck library.

Answer (score 0):

In my case: I have installed QT 32 bit lib in Win10 64 bit and it ran into error, I change to all 64 bit and QT creator run smoothly.

Answer (score -1):

Solved this problem just a minute ago in suse.
Just do the following step below and QTCreator should works just fine.

sudo zypper install --type pattern devel_basis