# "/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL" when building a Qt application

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I installed Linux Debian yesterday and then the latest Qt version. Today I installed gcc and g++. But the problem is, it doesn't build and run when I create a GUI Application.

Whenever I create a new Project, select the gui and don't even change anything it doesn't compile and I get this message :

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [untitled] Error 1
14:17:36: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project untitled (kit: Desktop Qt 5.1.1 GCC 64bit)
When executing step 'Make'

Seems like I'm missing a library but I don't know how to install it. I don't even know which one it is.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: How did you configure, build, and install Qt? Can't you use the packaged Qt( (by `aptitude install libqt5-dev`)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Qt: can't find -lGL error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18406369/qt-cant-find-lgl-error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

apt-get install libgl1-mesa-glx

The dev packages are actually not the problem. You have a linker error, not a compiler error.

Depending on your graphic card you might use specialized OpenGL implementation, e.g. something like `libgl1-nvidia-glx` fror NVIDA cards.

Comment: The problem is there's no OpenGL library to link with.

Comment: That's what I wrote: The problem is not the dev package. The dev package would pull in the lib, too, but the include files, which are also in the dev package, are not strictly necessary for his problem.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, you need to install openGL dev package. Sorry, don't remember the package name.