# How to run c/c++ app in QT Creator on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, c, qt, ubuntu, qt5

I have Ubuntu 13.04 on my PC and QT Creator

When I try to run c/c++ simple application I says that:

"QT Creator needs a compiler set up to build. Configure compiler in the kit options"

Then I go to the Tools->Options->Build&Run->Kits
and I see that in Auto-detected there is "Desktop Qt 5.2.1 GCC 32bit (default)"
but before it there is a ! and it says that "Error:no compiler set in kit"

I really can't get it. THere are a lot of tutorials, but nothig said about such a situation.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the steps you can follow after downloading the correct 32 or 64 bit package from the [Qt download page](http://qt-project.org/downloads).

**Change permissions and install Qt.**

```
chmod +x qt-linux-opensource-5.0.2-x86-offline.run
./qt-linux-opensource-5.0.2-x86-offline.run
```

**Install build essentials**

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

**Install OpenGL**

```
sudo apt-get install mesa-common-dev
```

**Configure the compiler**

Launch Qt Creator. Go to Tools > Options. Click Build & Run and select tab Kit. Configure a compiler if it is not automatically detected.

If you get any build isses related to linking in OpenGL (i.e. -lGL) then follow the answer below:

[Qt: can't find -lGL error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18406369/qt-creator-cant-find-lgl-error)

Referenced Website(s):

http://qt-project.org/wiki/Install_Qt_5_on_Ubuntu

Comment: Please refrain from link-only answers. This not a good way of writing answers.

Comment: @LaszloPapp Thanks for the feedback I didn't know it was poor form on SO. I've updated my answer and cited the sources to avoid the link-only answer.