# Qt Creator compiler issue on Debian

Tags: c++, qt

I have correctly installed Qt Creator on my Debian virtual machine, but I'm getting error when trying to compile default Qt project: **cannot find -lGL**. I searched for solution on Google, but every solution I found didn't helped me, even if the problems were almost the same. I would like someone to explain me what's happening, why that library cannot be found?

I installed libglu1-mesa-dev package, but that didn't solved the problem. I spent few days to configure Qt on my machine, but really I have no idea how to solve this library problem?

This [Qt: can't find -lGL error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18406369/qt-cant-find-lgl-error) didn't solved my problem.

Output of ldconfig -p | grep GL command is:

```
    libGLU.so.1 (libc6) => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGLU.so.1
    libGLEW.so.1.7 (libc6) => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGLEW.so.1.7
    libGL.so.1 (libc6, OS ABI: Linux 2.4.20) => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Qt: can't find -lGL error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18406369/qt-cant-find-lgl-error)

Comment: I tried with that but it doesn't solve anything!

Comment: you need to install `libgl1-mesa-dev`, as described in the linked duplicate; you only installed `libglu1-mesa-dev` (package name with `u`)

Comment: I tried that also but It doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution for my problem, so I'll share it with all of you.

As I described in question, I had a problem when trying to compile default project on Debian Qt Creator cross-compiler.

I lacked the two libraries **libglu1-mesa-dev** and **libgl1-mesa-dev**

I tried to get them via **sudo apt-get install libglu1-mesa-dev libgl1-mesa-dev**, but I kept receiving errors **W:Failed to fetch..** and I succeeded to solve this problem doing these three steps:

1. sudo bash -c 'echo "nameserver 127.0.0.1" >> /etc/resolv.conf'
2. sudo apt-get update
3. sudo apt-get install libglu1-mesa-dev libgl1-mesa-dev

I hope this helps to everyone who lacks any type of library not just these two!