# QT designer and creater

Tags: qt

please I create a Qt widgets application with the default options but when i run it it's not working and these errors appear
I'm using ubuntu 17.04 and Qt version 5.0.2

:-1: error: cannot find -lGL

:-1: error: collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

```
    #ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Comment: do you have opengl installed?

Comment: @Simon
thanks for reply
yes it's installed


glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version"

OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 17.0.7

Comment: what operation system you are using?

Comment: Install `libqt5opengl5-dev`

Comment: @Simon
I'm using ubuntu 17.04 and Qt version 5.0.2

Answer (score 0):

Install for ubuntu

```
apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev
```

Fedora

```
dnf install mesa-libGL-devel
```

Comment: root@Hossam-PC:/home/hossam# sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libgl1-mesa-dev

Comment: Try to create [soft link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18406369/qt-cant-find-lgl-error)

Comment: thanks the problem has been solved with the soft link