# Trying to compile a cross platform QT based app but always getting this error: usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL

Tags: qt, ubuntu, cross-platform, blockchain, lib

Trying to compile a cross platform QT based app with QT5 open source. But always getting this error. 
My platform (OS) Linux ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS 64 bit

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Qt: can't find -lGL error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18406369/qt-cant-find-lgl-error)

Comment: [Qt - Requirement for development host](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/linux.html#requirements-for-development-host)