# Which libGL to use for Android emulator in Fedora 64 bit?

Tags: android, linux, android-emulator, fedora

I'm using Fedora 19 64 bit (GNOME 3) for Android development.

`locate libGL` gives me:

```
/home/ericnguyen/adt/sdk/tools/lib/libGLES_CM_translator.so
/home/ericnguyen/adt/sdk/tools/lib/libGLES_V2_translator.so
/usr/lib/libGL.so.1
/usr/lib/libGL.so.1.2.0
/usr/lib64/libGL.so.1
/usr/lib64/libGL.so.1.2.0
/usr/lib64/libGLU.so.1
/usr/lib64/libGLU.so.1.3.1
/usr/share/doc/mesa-libGL-9.2
/usr/share/doc/mesa-libGL-9.2/COPYING
```

Right now I'm not able to start the emulator using my computer's GPU
Failed to load libGL.so
error libGL.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

So, I'm trying to find the appropriate libGL.so file to do as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11332817/failed-to-load-libgl-so-in-android).

Also, when I:

```
yum install mesa-libGL.x86_64
```

I got:

```
Package mesa-libGL-9.2-0.14.20130723.fc19.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

**Notes:**
I'm able to run the emulator without the GPU just fine.

My graphics card is AMD ATI Radeon HD 5000 series. I don't think I have installed any driver for it yet. I did `yum search radeon` and found `xorg-x11-drv-ati.x86_64` but I'm not sure whether that's the correct driver - I have found people running into startup problem trying to install graphic card drivers (my own experience with Windows) so I'm a little uncertain right now.
I am also aware that one will need to install proprietary software from AMD/ ATI to to be able to use the graphics card.

Comment: What GPU card are you using, and what drivers do you have installed?

Comment: I've update my answer with extra info.  I hope that helps at least get you on your way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The emulator is a 32-bit app.  You need to install the equivalent 32-bit  libraries.  From the Fedora wiki [HOWTO Setup Android Development](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/HOWTO_Setup_Android_Development/) the recommended libraries are:

> glibc.i686 glibc-devel.i686 
>   libstdc++.i686 zlib-devel.i686
>   ncurses-devel.i686 libX11-devel.i686 
>   libXrender.i686 libXrandr.i686

If you can run the emulator without GPU support I will assume you have all of those.

For mesa-libGL your yum command is attempting to install the 64-bit version of the library, so try this instead:

```
yum install mesa-libGL.i686
```

**EDIT (after Question update):**

Yes install the The xorg-x11-drv-ati driver if it isn't already.  This is the opensource driver and if it doesn't work you should just drop back to whatever you are running now.

I have an Nvidia card, but have had this running with my previous ATI card.  I assume something has changed with the emulator since I set mine up a while ago as it seems to be running with the 64bit libraries:

```
$ pldd 9989 



...
...
./lib/lib64OpenglRender.so
/opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/./lib/../lib/lib64EGL_translator.so
/usr/lib64/nvidia-304xx/libGL.so.1
/usr/lib64/nvidia-304xx/tls/libnvidia-tls.so.304.88
/usr/lib64/nvidia-304xx/libnvidia-glcore.so.304.88
/opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/./lib/../lib/lib64GLES_CM_translator.so
/opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/./lib/../lib/lib64GLES_V2_translator.so
/lib64/libGL.so
/lib64/libglapi.so.0
/lib64/libXdamage.so.1
/lib64/libX11-xcb.so.1
/lib64/libxcb-glx.so.0
/lib64/libxcb-dri2.so.0
...
...
..
....
```

(9989 being the process id of the running emulator.)

So installing the drivers you have already mentioned *should* be enough.

You can test if the emulator is using them with just the emulator and the [JellyBean Easter Egg](http://www.engadget.com/2012/06/27/google-jelly-bean-easter-egg-video-android-4-1/).

```
emulator -avd <your_avd_name> -gpu on
```

should give you noticeably better performance than

```
emulator -avd <your_avd_name> -gpu off
```

A little extra info:

You can install the proprietary driver xorg-x11-drv-catalyst, if you want to try it, from [RPM Fussion](http://rpmfusion.org/) and will find it in the non-free repo there.

If you don't have them already have RPM Fussion repos on your system (detailed instructions on there site.)  I strongly recommend them.  They are well supported and will give you less headaches than using some of Fedora equivalents (they return mp3 support to packages, for example.)

You say you are new to Linux (or maybe you mean playing with drivers on Linux) either way an FYI: You don't need to include the target platform when install packages (i.e. the .x86_64 .i686) Yum will sort that out for you unless you need libraries for an architecture other than the one you are running.

Comment: Thanks @Chilledrat, the main question is which libGL library to install though