# Run android emulator on headless linux machine

Tags: android, linux, android-emulator, adb, headless

I am trying to run android emulator on my linux headless machine. I install android sdk, required platofrms and so on. I already created android **avd** using following command

```
android create avd -n TestDevice4.4.2 -t 17 ( 17 is id of from targets list )
```

Now i try to start emulator by following command

```
emulator -avd TestDevice4.4.2 -no-skin -no-window
```

And i got the following error on my terminal.

> /home/ubuntu/sdk-android/tools/emulator64-arm: error while loading
>   shared libraries: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such
>   file or directory

Since it is the first time setting up from termial in headless linux machine, i faced several issues. I can't figure out what's going on with this one. Appreciate your help :-)

**EDITED** 
I've seen similar issues [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11332817/failed-to-load-libgl-so-on-android). I had to install following library and create symbolink in sdk/tools/lib dir.

```
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev
ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.2.0 libGL.so
```

After done these steps, i start emulator again. i got following problem :-(

> sh: 1: glxinfo: not found emulator: 
>   ERROR: This AVD's configuration is
>   missing a kernel file!! emulator: ERROR: ANDROID_SDK_ROOT is undefined

Comment: Even though you have no screen, doesn't mean you don't need a graphics-capable device. You are missing a GL (graphics library). Go ahead and install the drivers for your device.

Comment: Thanks , i will try this out .

Comment: Similar issue here, using Centos 7 and avdmanager

Answer (score 1):

For each version of Android you want to run, install at least:

1) Platform SDK (eg 17 for 4.2 version)

2) A system image for the emulator (eg ARM EABI v7a System Image )

bye

Comment: Launch Android SDK manager:  
cd /xxxxx/sdk/tools  (hit enter)
just type ./android

Comment: Thanks @ariel-giomi . I use Jenkins emulator instead trying to create it on my own . I will post in answer .

Comment: I will use Jenkins too. Did you find the answer? @Sanny